# Keycloak Import Realm "Create" From Java?

Tags: java, rest, keycloak

I've tried to import a realm from java application, 
but the server always return:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:197)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.DefaultEntityExtractorFactory$3.extractEntity(DefaultEntityExtractorFactory.java:50)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:104)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:64)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.create(Unknown Source)
at com.blulogix.core.rest.util.TestKeycloakToken.createRealm(TestKeycloakToken.java:59)
at com.blulogix.core.rest.util.TestKeycloakToken.main(TestKeycloakToken.java:38)
```

and this is my code:

```
     Keycloak kc = Keycloak.getInstance("http://localhost:8080/auth", "master", "admin", "admin", "security-admin-console");
     RealmRepresentation rr = new RealmRepresentation();
     rr.setId("TestRealm2");
     rr.setRealm("TestRealm2");
     rr.setEnabled(true);
```

Code for adding a new user to any realm are worked.

```
   kc.realm("master").users().create(user);
```

Please, Can anyone help me out with importing realm??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not telling us which Keycloak version you are using.
Assuming it is 1.7.0 or newer I suggest using "admin-cli" rather than "security-admin-console" to connect to Keycloak.

See the "Migrating to 1.7.0.CR1" section in the user guide 
http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/topics/MigrationFromOlderVersions.html (on this page search for 1.7.0)

Comment: change the link ,your shared link in the answer is dead now.

Comment: One question is this possible to create Realm through REST API of keycloak?

Comment: Yes. All keycloak objects can be managed through the REST API. For realms see [Keycloak Realms Admin](http://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.3/rest-api/index.html#_realms_admin_resource)

Comment: Thanks for your reply its more llok like import rather create rest . Is it now? Or both are same what will be proper rest url and request data for this .

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the import for org.apache.httpcomponents version "4.3.6".