# Error 400 bad request when creating keycloak roles in Java

Tags: java, keycloak

I try to create a Keycloak role from my Java program. I am able to create user so it's not a problem of connection to my Keycloak server but the create function for the role always give me an error 400 bad request. What is the solution to create a role from Java?

```java
Keycloak kc = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/auth")
            .realm("master")
            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
            .username("***")
            .password("***")
            .clientId("admin-cli")
            .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
            .build();

RoleRepresentation roleRepresentation = new RoleRepresentation();
roleRepresentation.setName(nomRole);
roleRepresentation.setClientRole(true);
kc.realm("master").roles().create(roleRepresentation);
```

> error : 
>   Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:215)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.DefaultEntityExtractorFactory$3.extractEntity(DefaultEntityExtractorFactory.java:50)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:150)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.create(Unknown Source)
>       at Main.CreateKeycloakRole(Main.java:37)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:96)

Comment: Have a look at this ink: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041604/keycloak-import-realm-create-from-java?rq=1

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing same exception when creating roles.

Comment: I didn't find any solution. I am using version 4.5.0 final. I will try with the 4.8.3 as Kohei say in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with the Keycloak 4.8.3 version and now it is working as expected ! I think my version was too old to handle role creation ! For me the solution was just to take a newer version ! Thanks all for your help !

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible cause is `nomRole` is null.

I can create a role using your code with Keycloak client 4.8.3 and Keycloak server 4.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to the latest jboss/keycloak image and the same code worked for me

Comment: Please add this as a comment ,sooner or later this question will down vote.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurred to me when `Consent Required` was set to `ON` for a client.
If I set it as `OFF` it works, I am looking into an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should make client access type be set to "public" (not only ), it's important

Comment: A bit explanation will help the others